# Make controller more efficient by choosing method dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have these two methods in my repository:

```
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts
    {
        get { return context.Posts; }
    }


    public IEnumerable<Editables> Editables
    {
        get { return context.Editables; 
    }
```

Here is my method:

```
 public ActionResult SaveEdit(int activeid,string text, string prop, string REPOMETHOD)
        {
            var elementToEdit = _repository.<dynamic insert Post or Editable>.ElementAt(activeid);
            var type = elementToEdit.GetType();
            PropertyInfo p = type.GetProperty(prop);
            p.SetValue(elementToEdit, text, null);

            _repository.UpdateBigLinkEdit(elementToEdit, activeid);

            return null;
        }
```

So, ii it possible to make this methid more dynamic and insert the right method

```
_repository.Editables.ElementAt(activeid)  OR  _repository.Post.ElementAt(activeid);
```

By passing the name of the nethod from my view? Or do I have to go about it another way?

Comment: There is a benefit to code sharing and minimizing duplication, but it's at the expense of readability and maintainability. Even if you could get this working, it will just confuse anyone else that has to maintain this code. My advice is to split it out and leave it separate.

Comment: @DaveZych What if he have 10 or more classes that needs to "use" this same method. Do you think it is better to have a saparate save-method/if-statements/switch for every class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, by using a generic method:

```
public T GetElement<T>(int id)
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(Post)) return Posts.ElementAt(id);
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(Editable)) return Editables.ElementAt(id);
  throw new InvalidTypeException();
}
```

and then to use it

```
var element = _repository.GetElement<Post>(activeId);
```

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna take a closer look at this!

Comment: @Kjata30, fixed by adding an exception which they can change to their liking.

Answer (score 1):

If the usage of either `Posts` or `Editables` objects are conditional on user input, you should have separate controller methods to handle each request. You can still reuse code by having them each call the same method:

```
public ActionResult Save(int activeId, string text)
{
   var elementToEdit = _repository.Posts.ElementAt(activeid);
   return SaveEdit(activeId, text, elementToEdit);
}

public ActionResult Edit(int activeId, string text)
{
   var elementToEdit = _repository.Editables.ElementAt(activeId);
   return SaveEdit(activeId, text, elementToEdit);
}

private ActionResult SaveEdit(int activeId, string text, object elementToEdit)
{
   // logic from your original method
}
```

If the condition to use either object is **not** contingent on user input, you should be able to use an `if` conditional to set the `elementToEdit` object in your original code example.

Comment: And an `if` statement in a generic method, per user145400, would be an elegant approach.